# Can you get the selected leaf from a DecisionTreeRegressor in scikit-learn

Tags: python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

just reading this [great paper](http://quinonero.net/Publications/predicting-clicks-facebook.pdf) and trying to implement this:

*... We treat each individual
tree as a categorical feature that takes as value the
index of the leaf an instance ends up falling in. We use 1-
of-K coding of this type of features. For example, consider
the boosted tree model in Figure 1 with 2 subtrees, where
the first subtree has 3 leafs and the second 2 leafs. If an
instance ends up in leaf 2 in the first subtree and leaf 1 in
second subtree, the overall input to the linear classifier will
be the binary vector [0, 1, 0, 1, 0], where the first 3 entries
correspond to the leaves of the first subtree and last 2 to
those of the second subtree ...*

Anyone know how I can predict a bunch of rows and for each of those rows get the selected leaf for each tree in the ensemble?  For this use case I don't really care what the node represents, just its index really.  Had a look at the source and I could not quickly see anything obvious.  I can see that I need to iterate the trees and do something like this:

```
for sample in X_test:
  for tree in gbc.estimators_:
    leaf = tree.leaf_index(sample) # This is the function I need but don't think exists.
    ...
```

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[DecisionTreeRegressor](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.tree.DecisionTreeRegressor.html) has `tree_` property which gives you access to the underlying decision tree. It has method [`apply`](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/tree/_tree.pyx#L3215), which seemingly finds corresponding leaf id:

```
dt.tree_.apply(X)
```

Note that `apply` expects its input to have type `float32`.

Comment: yeah I see how I can iterate through nodes but how can I determine the terminal leaf without having to traverse each node and check for thresholds, infact this is quite hard as GBC does feature sub samples right? So I would have to account for selected features for that tree also.

Comment: @gatapia, I updated my answer, it turned out there is such a function in sklearn.

Answer (score 3):

The following function goes beyond identifying the selected leaf from the Decision Tree and implements the application in the referenced paper. Its use is the same as the referenced paper, where I use the GBC for feature engineering.

```
def makeTreeBins(gbc, X):
    '''
    Takes in a GradientBoostingClassifier object (gbc) and a data frame (X).
    Returns a numpy array of dim (rows(X), num_estimators), where each row represents the set of terminal nodes
    that the record X[i] falls into across all estimators in the GBC. 

    Note, each tree produces 2^max_depth terminal nodes. I append a prefix to the terminal node id in each incremental
    estimator so that I can use these as feature ids in other classifiers.
    '''
    for i, dt_i in enumerate(gbc.estimators_):

        prefix = (i + 2)*100 #Must be an integer

        nds = prefix + dt_i[0].tree_.apply(np.array(X).astype(np.float32))

        if i == 0:
            nd_mat = nds.reshape(len(nds), 1)        

        else:
            nd_mat = np.hstack((nd, nds.reshape(len(nds), 1)))

return nd_mat
```

Comment: how come this is answering the question ?

Comment: It shows how to get the leaf node for every record in a data frame, for every tree in a gradient boosting classifier. It specifically addresses how to implement the methods in the referenced paper.

Comment: Ok thanks. Try avoiding words like I had same question, directly try to give answer , else some will get confused and flag the answer

Comment: nd_mat = np.hstack((nd, nds.reshape(len(nds), 1))) should be np.hstack((nd_map, nds.reshape(len(nds), 1)))