# How can I output the node making a prediction using sklearn.tree?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, regression

I would like to obtain all information of a node making a prediction using sklearn.tree.

For example:

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
nfrom sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
clf = DecisionTreeClassifier()
iris = load_iris()
clf = clf.fit(iris.data, iris.target)
```

Now we can predict the class using:

```
clf.predict(iris.data[0, :])
```

How can I obtain the leaf node making the prediction and also the information stored in the leaf?

I know that the graphical representation of the tree for the above example is the following:

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/tree.html#tree-classification

So I know that the node corresponding to the input *iris.data[0, :]* (first left child) has the following statistics:

- error=0
- samples=50
- value = [50 0 0]

Is it possible to obtain the output node and the (above) information automatically without printing the tree? From my current understaning the key thing is to obtain the *ID* of the leaf node making the prediction, the relevant statistics are then contained in *clf.tree_.value[ID]* and *clf.tree_.n_samples[ID]*.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27654635/1190430) question. It says how to obtain leaf's ID. Then you can use those `clf.tree_.value` and `clf.tree.n_samples`.

Comment: Thanks! X=((iris.data[0, :]).astype(np.float32)).reshape(1,-1) and then clf.tree_.apply(X)[0] returns the proper node